# What is the MSR differences between AMD x86 and Intel x86?

Tags: x86, intel, amd-processor, msr

I know both the AMD and Intel implement the x86 architecture CPU, both of them contains the MSR registers. I am not sure if the MSR registers in both implementation are the same.
If not, what is the main differences?

Comment: There are a boatload of different MSRs.  Many of them are documented by both Intel and AMD, and/or indicated by CPUID feature bits.  e.g. the entry point for `syscall` is set by an MSR, and of course both Intel and AMD support it.  Can you be more specific about which area of functionality you're interested in?

Comment: Let's start that MSR = Model Specific Registers. It clearly indicates they are not only specific to manufacturer but also can be different across different families.

Comment: First, thank you for your reply. Sorry for the confusion, actually I just want to know if there are common MSR sets that are shared by both Intel and AMD, and are there any specific  MSRs that are specific to Intel or AMD. From Anty's comments, it seems like thery are specific only only to the manafacturers, but also to the different families. I think Anty has answered my question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Anty: They *can* be model/vendor specific, but some of them are *not*.  e.g. `IA32_LSTAR` is the entry point for [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html), and I think AMD and Intel use the same MSR number for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine Peter and Anty's comments, I think I have get the answer.
"MSR = Model Specific Registers. It clearly indicates they are not only specific to manufacturer but also can be different across different families."
Theoretically, the MSR registers are vendor and mode specific, but in reality, as Peter mentioned, Intel and AMD may use the same MSR for the same feature, such as the IA32_LSTAR MSR register.

Comment: That wasn't a complete answer.  They *can* be different, but there is overlap in some, like (I think) `IA32_LSTAR`, which is the entry point for [`syscall`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSCALL.html).  (And BTW, "see comments" is not an answer either; you should quote the relevant parts to make the answer self-contained.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I will conbine both you and Anty's answer.